# TextView height increase when decreasing font size

Tags: android, textview, height, font-size

I'm developing a Sudoku Game and am having problems with textViews' heights. As in any Sudoku, the user has the option to enter a digit or put some hints. Digits work fine with Fontsize 14, but when I change the hint font size to 7 (dip or sp), the textView height is increased although there is a lot of space around (the same for font size 6 and even with 1 line of text). How do I fix the textView height regardless of the textsize.

Here is the layout portion:

```
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TableRow01" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/line_v" android:digits="@string/inpt"
            android:width="34dip" android:text="1" android:drawableTop="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/line_v" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV00" android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:height="34dip"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_h"
            android:digits="@string/inpt" android:width="30dip" android:text="2"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/line_h" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV01" android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:height="34dip"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/line_v" android:digits="@string/inpt"
            android:width="34dip" android:text="2" android:drawableTop="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/line_v" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV02" android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:height="34dip"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/line_v" android:digits="@string/inpt"
            android:width="34dip" android:text="1" android:drawableTop="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/line_v" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV03" android:paddingLeft="1dip" android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:height="34dip"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_h"
            android:digits="@string/inpt" android:width="30dip" android:text="2"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/line_h" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV04" android:clickable="true"
            android:height="34dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/line_v" android:digits="@string/inpt"
            android:width="34dip" android:text="2" android:drawableTop="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/line_v" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV05" android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:height="34dip"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/line_v" android:digits="@string/inpt"
            android:width="34dip" android:text="1" android:drawableTop="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/line_v" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV06" android:paddingLeft="1dip" android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:height="34dip"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_h"
            android:digits="@string/inpt" android:width="30dip" android:text="2"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/line_h" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV07" android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:height="34dip"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/line_v" android:digits="@string/inpt"
            android:width="34dip" android:drawableTop="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/line_v" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV08" android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:height="34dip" android:text="1 2 3"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TableRow02"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableRight="@drawable/line_v"
            android:digits="@string/inpt" android:width="32dip" android:text="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/line_v" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV10" android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:height="32dip"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:digits="@string/inpt" android:width="30dip"
            android:text="2" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:id="@+id/TV11"
            android:clickable="true" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:height="32dip"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableRight="@drawable/line_v"
            android:digits="@string/inpt" android:width="32dip" android:text="2"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/line_v" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV12" android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:height="32dip"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableRight="@drawable/line_v"
            android:digits="@string/inpt" android:width="32dip" android:text="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/line_v" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV13" android:paddingLeft="1dip" android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:height="32dip"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:digits="@string/inpt" android:width="30dip"
            android:text="2" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:id="@+id/TV14"
            android:clickable="true" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:height="32dip"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableRight="@drawable/line_v"
            android:digits="@string/inpt" android:width="34dip" android:text="2"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/line_v" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV15" android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:height="32dip"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableRight="@drawable/line_v"
            android:digits="@string/inpt" android:width="34dip" android:text="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/line_v" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV16" android:paddingLeft="1dip" android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:height="32dip"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:digits="@string/inpt" android:width="30dip"
            android:text="2" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:id="@+id/TV17"
            android:clickable="true" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:height="32dip"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableRight="@drawable/line_v"
            android:digits="@string/inpt" android:width="34dip" android:text="2"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/line_v" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV18" android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:height="32dip"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the what you see with size 14 and size 7 fonts?

Comment: @slayton: Sorry, I am new to stackoverflow and I'm not allowed to post images yet. However, if I change the textSize (at runtime or in the layout viewer) the whole row's height is increased.

Comment: Consider using a gridview instead of a tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my question without the need to redo my code & design with gridview (thanks slayton for your suggestion, but I found an easier workaround).

I don't completely understand why but after playing around with the textviews' properties, I found that when I change the textsize of one textview to 7 (or any other value actually) I need to change its layoutheight to Fill_Parent (but keep all textViews in the row with size 14 with layoutheight Wrap_Content). I do this programmatically. The new layout is

```
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/TableRow01" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/line_v" android:digits="@string/inpt"
            android:width="34dip" android:text="1" android:drawableTop="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/line_v" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV00" android:clickable="true"
            android:height="34dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_h"
            android:digits="@string/inpt" android:width="30dip" android:text="2"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/line_h" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV01" android:clickable="true"
            android:height="34dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/line_v" android:digits="@string/inpt"
            android:width="34dip" android:text="2" android:drawableTop="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/line_v" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV02" android:clickable="true"
            android:height="34dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/line_v" android:digits="@string/inpt"
            android:width="34dip" android:text="1" android:drawableTop="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/line_v" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV03" android:paddingLeft="1dip" android:clickable="true"
            android:height="34dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_h"
            android:digits="@string/inpt" android:width="30dip" android:text="2"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/line_h" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV04" android:clickable="true"
            android:height="34dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/line_v" android:digits="@string/inpt"
            android:width="34dip" android:text="2" android:drawableTop="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/line_v" android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV05" android:clickable="true"
            android:height="34dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/line_v" android:digits="@string/inpt"
            android:width="34dip" android:text="1" android:drawableTop="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/line_v" android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV06" android:paddingLeft="1dip" android:clickable="true"
            android:height="34dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_h"
            android:digits="@string/inpt" android:width="30dip" android:drawableTop="@drawable/line_h" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV07" android:clickable="true"
            android:height="34dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:maxHeight="34dip" android:maxWidth="30dip" android:gravity="center" android:text="2" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <TextView android:typeface="monospace" android:drawableBottom="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/line_v" android:digits="@string/inpt"
            android:width="34dip" android:drawableTop="@drawable/line_h"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/line_v" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/TV08" android:clickable="true"
            android:height="34dip" android:maxHeight="34dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="center" android:text="2" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    </TableRow>
```

And I use code to change the size & the layoutheight together:

```
    tv.setTextSize(7);
tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));


    tv.setTextSize(14);
tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```